# How to solve an extension of the rule of 3 problem when the relationship isn´t linear

Tags: logic

12593 is to 35291
and 29684 is to 46982
therefore 72936 is to ?

I tried thinking of each pair of numbers as a point in (x,y) and get the general function but it doesn´t lead to an even number, which I´m guessing is the idea.

It seems that if you think of every number as multiple digits, so 12593 would be 1 | 2 | 5 | 9 | 3, then you can get to 3 | 5 | 2 | 9 | 1 by adding 2 | 3 | -3 | 0 | 2. And in the case of 2 | 9 |6 | 8 | 4 you would have to add 2 | -3 | 3 | 0 | -2. There might be something there but I´m new to this sort of problem

Comment: What is the rule of $3$ problem?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking.  Your first sentence appears to be a simple recognition of a permutation on $5$ letters $ABCDE\mapsto ECBDA$. I have no idea what the rest of your post has to do with it.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn´t clear, my question was how to solve for the last relationship based of the previous ones. I hadn´t noticed the permutation, which is the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In each of the two complete examples the second and third digits switch places...